# Replace , with . in input field bound to property using Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-model

I have an input field that is supposed to contain numbers.
It is bound to an object property.
I want input entered as 4,5 to automatically get converted to 4.5 in both model and view.

#### HTML:

```
<input data-ng-model="productContent(product.Id).Org" value="{{productContent(product.Id).Org | replaceComma}}" />
```

Control:

```
$scope.productContent = function (prodId) {
    var content = $.grep($scope.productsContent, function (el) { return el.ProdId === prodId });
    return content[0];}
```

#### Filter:

```
app.filter('replaceComma', function () {
            return function (val) {
                return (typeof val) == "string" ? val.toString().trim().replace(",", ".") : val
            };
        });
```

#### Result:

When I enter a number, at first the model (productContent) retrieves the correct object. Then the filter code is called and returns a correctly converted string. I would expect both the model and view to be updated to the filtered value, but both are updated with the unfiltered value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in the past but instead of creating my own filter, I took a different path and found something ready to use instead.

angular-input-masks by assisrafael one of my favourite angular extensions for this purpose:

https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

Examples:

http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/

Since the author has written the documentation, I don't want to get extensive on it and be outdated in the future. As a quick reference, look for [ui-number-mask](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks#ui-number-mask).

Maybe this is not a direct answer to your question, since it's not replacing commas with periods, but making you type the decimals instead.

On a side note, you can suppress the thousands separators with `ui-hide-group-sep`

I hope that's helpful, otherwise leave a comment and I'll be happy to continue to assist you!

-Helvio